# Why can't you set max_width for containers?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, css

I have this XML here, and I want to set the max_width for the linear layout to 600dp or something. Why doesn't Android allow this?

EDIT: The question is **WHY**, not *how*. E.g., **why** would the Android team decide to have it like this?

```
       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/details_type_info_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ¿¿¿android:max_width = "600dp"???
        android:background="@color/light_grey"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_type_info_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="@string/placeholder" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_text_info_source"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/details_source"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: BTW, I fixed this using `width="match_parent"` as default, and `width="600dp"` for screens that have more available width than 600dp. But this is not an all-purpose solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, I guess it was just a design <strike>oversight</strike> decision from the Android team.

Glad you found a solution. Another approach would be to stick it inside another container with an absolute width set. Why 600dp, though? If the screen's got more room, limiting it to a hard value has a high potential to look weird.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand your solution. Won't `
`width="match_parent"` make the inner container the same fixed size as the outer container?

The idea was that the LinearLayout was as wide as the screen, up to a point. For wide screens, it looked weird to fill the entire screen. (I also have a separate landscape layout, no worries.)

Example:
http://blogs.publishersweekly.com/blogs/PWxyz/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Screen-shot-2011-01-20-at-12.59.55-PM.jpg

Comment: Nowhere did I say `width="match_parent"` ;) Try `wrap_content` on the inner container, and see if the hard outer dimension is an effective limit. I don't have an environment in front of me to try it out, but I think it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

android:max_width  attribute didn't define for LinearLayout.you should use other way for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Fragments? With it you can achieve the same but as for me with Fragments your code will be more graceful ([See description of fragment object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html))